# How can I update only newly added repositories?

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` it wastes time updating PPAs that are already up to date. Is there a command that does the same with more efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

**In the following remove tick for all and make tick for the PPA you want and run `sudo apt-get update`**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Run `sudo software-properties-gtk` to get this**

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really download anything already up to date, it just checks whether the `PPA` it's actually up to date: you can try it for yourself by running `sudo apt-get update` twice after a while that it hasn't been run; you'll see that at the first run some updates will be downloaded, while at the second run they won't.